# I am writing code for Quiz using html, javascript. But it is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following for Quiz questions. Questions are not displaying . I am put my code in following link.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id='container'>
    <div id='title'>
      <h1>Learning Js Properly: Project #1 - Dynamic Quiz</h1>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id='quiz'></div>
    <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
    <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></div>
    <div class='button' id='start'> <a href='#'>Start Over</a></div>
    <!-- <button class='' id='next'>Next</a></button>
            <button class='' id='prev'>Prev</a></button>
            <button class='' id='start'> Start Over</a></button> -->
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnnqqsmj/

Please correct me where i am putting wrong code. Please help me on this issue.

```
(function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 2*5?",
    choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }, {
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Animates buttons on hover
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value=' + selections[questionCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if (questionCounter === 1) {
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if (questionCounter === 0) {

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      } else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }

    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
      questions.length + ' right!!!');
    return score;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Ironically the code at the JSFiddle contains everything *except*  the one line that's in the question itself (it works fine if you include jQuery).

Comment: JJJ is correct, just include jQuery - as long as it is at the END of the body in this case, otherwise Ryan is correct i.e. execute once the document is ready.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnnqqsmj/1/

You need to put this code inside a `$(document).ready();`

You are using a self-executing anonymous function which runs when it is called but the elements you are referencing haven't been loaded into the DOM yet so JS doesn't know about them.  Wait until the document is fully loaded before trying to access DOM elements.

Comment: This ensures proper execution no matter if jQuery is in the head OR end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnnqqsmj/4/). It seems you are writing the js code inside the header tag. Unless you add `document.ready` that will create the problem.

You can still go without `document .ready` if you add the scripts near the closing `body` tag

```
<body>
  // HTML code
<script>
 // js code
</script>
</body>
```